# Importing a no-disposed frames animated GIF into Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gif, import

I've been mucking about with animated GIFs for a while now, but I've only come across these in the last two days.

The last two times I just manually flipped on the layers frame by frame to create the "Do Not Dispose" effect, now I have a much longer GIF and just telling Photoshop to "Do Not Dispose" all the frames isn't cutting it

What I think is happening is the original software is Not Disposing more than one frame, but Photoshop isn't capable of doing that.

For the comparison, note the cyan LED ticker in the middle, the smoke on the bottom left, and the light on the road when something is passing on the highway.

Original:

[image: see how good it looks]

Photoshop output:

[image: isn't this much worse?]

Comment: Are you suere photohop can not double frame numbers

Comment: I don't know what you mean, so no I am not sure.

Comment: You can right click on each frame to decide what it does. However for tis to work your layers need to have transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do this. Open the original image. then select ALL frames (click first one and then shift click last one), right click on any one of them, and select do not dispose. They are now all non disposing and when exporting with save for web work. It now works as intended.

[image]

**Image** Imported original and added some text (that does not dispose)

Its just very hard to work with these, since the effect is not reflected in the editor itself. So only way to see the final result is to export it. Consider using some other application.

So as a result you may not really know what you are doing